# Scope Pagination in OctoberCMS Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twig, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on Laravel. I'm not sure if this is an October issue or Laravel issue.

I use a [Dynamic Scope](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes) to filter database results form URL Parameter.
I'm not using the Record List drag and drop feature.

How do I [paginate](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/pagination) the results?

Edit:
I got page numbers to show using this, but clicking one does not go to the next page.

```
$this->page["scopeCategory"] = Gallery::applyCategory($category)->paginate(15);
```

#### The following example returns a list of image names from the nature category:

**URL**
`localhost/nature`

**Identifiers**
`/:category?latest/:page?`

### Model

**Scope**

```
public function scopeApplyCategory($query, $category = null) {
    return $query->where('category', $category);
}
```

### Page

**Code**

```
# Get URL Category Identifer
$category = $this->param('category');

# Create Twig Variable from Scope Apply
$this->page["scopeCategory"] = Gallery::applyCategory($category)->paginate(15);
```

**Markup**

```
<!-- Set Scope Variable -->
{% set scopeCategory = this.page.scopeCategory %}

<!-- List of Image Names filtered by Scope -->
{% for image in scopeCategory %}            
    {{ image.name }}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Paginate -->
{{ scopeCategory.render|raw }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved pagination issue in this way:

```
if($activity->lastPage() != 1){

        $page = \Request::get('page');

        $pagLink = " <ul class='pagination'>";
        $pagLink .= "<li>"; 
           for ($i=1; $i<=$activity->lastPage(); $i++) {
                     if($page == null && $i == 1){
                       $pagLink .= "<a class='active' href='activitylog?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
                      }else if($page == $i){
                       $pagLink .= "<a class='active' href='activitylog?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
                     }else{
                        $pagLink .= "<a href='activitylog?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
                     }
          }; 

        echo $pagLink . "</li></ul>";
 }
```

Comment: is this the solution in octobercms ??/